# How to create a migration *from* the database in dotnet core db migrations

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, migration, database-migration

So say I have a project with code first migrations set up, but changes end up getting applied in the IDE by a DBA or another developer, how can I create a migration to pull those changes into my project?

Without doing this, my next `update-database` command would wipe those changes.

Comment: Why not use database first instead?

Comment: I'm relatively new to ef migrations, but my understanding is that database first just means that you create an initial migration in VS and then it becomes a code first setup. Is that not the case?